# STRIPE API - Create payment link to custom account got wrong

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

How do i create payment link to custom account via stripe.net library?
I have tried with these codes but its created product and payment link to my stripe connected account instead of custom account as i want.

```
// create payment link
            var plinkOpt = new PaymentLinkCreateOptions
            {
                LineItems = new List<PaymentLinkLineItemOptions>
                {
                    new PaymentLinkLineItemOptions
                    {
                        Price = new PriceService().Create(
                            new PriceCreateOptions
                            {
                                Currency = "usd",
                                Product = new ProductService().Create(new ProductCreateOptions { Name = "myproductname", }).Id,
                                CustomUnitAmount = new PriceCustomUnitAmountOptions { Enabled = true },
                            }).Id,
                        Quantity = 1,
                    },
                },
            };

            var plinkSer = new PaymentLinkService();
            plinkSer.Create(plinkOpt);
```

I hope to have codes to solve my problem or a solution to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `StripeAccount` in `RequestOptions` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts?lang=dotnet)):

```
var options = new RequestOptions
{
  StripeAccount = "acct_123"
};
plinkSer.Create(plinkOpt, options);
```

Edit: However, this should only be used with Standard accounts, not custom accounts.

Comment: Its work bro, Thank you so much.
I still have one problem with my project about radar's rules. My stripe account has create many custom accounts with a customized rule but i can not find a way to change custom account radar rules. I could do it by my onboarding page but ii have to repeat the tasks (enable stripe radar, create rules) for every new custom account connected. Do you have experience about this problems?

Comment: With custom accounts you should be using destination charges, with all prices/payments/etc created on your platform. In this case, the payments will all use your platform's radar rules. Direct charges are not recommended for custom accounts. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types